# Handling disclaimers in a loop

Tags: python, selenium, loops, webdriver

I have a list of websites I want to visit with Selenium to download a document. Some websites require confirmation of location or simply a disclaimer.

As some websites repeat themselves in my list, is there a way to accept the disclaimer on the first visit via Selenium and don't look for the disclaimer on the 2nd, 3rd.. visit? Currently, I handle it with a **try, except**.

So it tries to accept the disclaimer and if it is not there (on 2nd visit and so in) it moves on.
However, as the program is waiting for the exception, it takes a good amount of time and time is a factor I want to improve on.
Any suggestions? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the assumption that you want to accept disclaimer on the first visit and after that visit, you don't want to accept the disclaimer, I can think of below approach

Create a map having String (URL) as key and boolean as a flag to check whether it is the first visit.

```
Map<String, Boolean> firstVisitTracker = new HashMap();

firstVisitTracker.put("www.google.com", true);
```

you can add all URL in the map and the default value for all URL will be true

now the code to accept the disclaimer can be written within if statement like

```
if(firstVisitTracker.get("www.google.com")){
    //code to accept disclaimer
    //Update firstVisitTracker to false value for visited website
    firstVisitTracker.put("www.google.com", false);
} else
   // code to proceed without accepting disclaimer
```

You can use this approach and tweak according to your requirements.
Also, I have provided pseudo-code in Java, you can replace them with python data structures

Hope this will help you.

Happy coding!